# Piping in Basic C shell exits the shell

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I have been trying to implement a basic C Shell and implement piping functionality for n number of commands. I am try to execute all the commands piped to each other and finally print the output on the STDOUT.

Based on the my implementation, my shell exits after executing the final command and then I am back to Linux Terminal. Please guide me on how to go about this.

```
typedef struct Command
{
    char** args;
    char* inFileName;
    char* outFileName;
    int isInputRedirected;
    int isOutputRedirected;
    int isOutputTruncated;
    int isExecuteInBackgrnd;
} Command;

typedef struct CommandList
{
    int numCmds;
    int isCommandsPiped;
    Command pCommand[MAX_NUM_PARALLEL_COMMANDS];
}CommandList;


int ExecuteMultipleCommandWithPipe(CommandList *cmdList)
{
        size_t i, n;
        int prev_pipe, pfds[2];
        n = cmdList->numCmds;
        prev_pipe = STDIN_FILENO;

        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            pipe(pfds);
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                // Redirect previous pipe to stdin
                if (prev_pipe != STDIN_FILENO) {
                    dup2(prev_pipe, STDIN_FILENO);
                    close(prev_pipe);
                }

                // Redirect stdout to current pipe
                dup2(pfds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(pfds[1]);

                // Start command
                execvp(cmdList->pCommand[i].args[0], cmdList->pCommand[i].args);
                PrintErrorMessage();
                exit(1);
            }

            // Close read end of previous pipe (not needed in the parent)
            close(prev_pipe);
            // Close write end of current pipe (not needed in the parent)
            close(pfds[1]);
            // Save read end of current pipe to use in next iteration
            prev_pipe = pfds[0];
        }

        // Get stdin from last pipe
        if (prev_pipe != STDIN_FILENO) {
            dup2(prev_pipe, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(prev_pipe);
        }

        // Start last command
        execvp(cmdList->pCommand[i].args[0], cmdList->pCommand[i].args);
        PrintErrorMessage();
        exit(1);
}
```

After the feedback, I have updated to code to execute all the piped commands in a for loop, but then I get strange issues. My parent program is NO more able to read from the `stdin`.
Here is the modified code:

```
/*
 * This function is used to execute multiple commands which are piped together.
 * */
int ExecuteMultipleCommandWithPipe(CommandList *cmdList)
{
        size_t i, n;
        int prev_pipe, pfds[2];
        n = cmdList->numCmds;
        prev_pipe = STDIN_FILENO;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            pipe(pfds);
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                // Redirect previous pipe to stdin
                if (prev_pipe != STDIN_FILENO) {
                    dup2(prev_pipe, STDIN_FILENO);
                    close(prev_pipe);
                }

                // Redirect stdout to current pipe
                if (i == n-1)
                {
                    dup2(pfds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                    close(pfds[1]);
                }

                // Start command
                execvp(cmdList->pCommand[i].args[0], cmdList->pCommand[i].args);
                PrintErrorMessage();
                exit(1);
            }

            // Close read end of previous pipe (not needed in the parent)
            close(prev_pipe);
            // Close write end of current pipe (not needed in the parent)
            close(pfds[1]);
            // Save read end of current pipe to use in next iteration
            prev_pipe = pfds[0];
        }

        close (prev_pipe);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't fork before executing the last command in the pipeline. So that `execvp()` replaces the shell with the program it executes.

Comment: You need *two* child-processes per pipe: One for the left-hand side and one for the right-hand side. Otherwise you replace the main shell process when you call `execvp`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude He's using `prev_pipe` to connect to the previous process.

Comment: @Barmar It's not a pipe issue, but a process issue. At `// Start last command` the OP is calling `execvp` in the parent (main shell) process.

Comment: ah! I get it. so for the last command, I need to run it in the same loop, and link the write pipe to the STD_OUT.

Comment: can someone help with the sample code? I tried to make the changes as given below, the parent program ends up in the endless loop.